# materializecss breaks plain ul/li rendering

Tags: html, materialize

I'm not looking for anything fancy, just the plain, old bullet-points rendering.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>a</li>
      <li>b</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`materialize.css` sets `list-style-type: none`, so adding

```
li {
    list-style-type: disc !important;
}
```

to the custom css brings back the default rendering: